# cross-fade gallery of images not pointing towards the right link on click

Tags: html, css, click, css-animations

I am working on a fiddle as shown below:

https://jsfiddle.net/t34kw6zj/7/embedded/result

The above fiddle shows cross fading gallery of images. Here is the snippet of CSS which I have used in order to achieve that:

```
.featured-block a {
-webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
    -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 8s;
    -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 16s;
    position:absolute !important;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

The above fiddle has 4 images with their respective links:

1. **logo1**  https://www.w3schools.com/
2. **logo2**  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
3. **logo3**  https://github.com/
4. **logo4**  https://www.espncricinfo.com/

On click of any logo (logo1 or logo2 or logo3 or logo4) above, its pointing to only one link (https://www.espncricinfo.com/)

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle above so that on click of any logo in the fiddle above it should point to the right link.

For example,

**=>** **on click of logo1** it should point to https://www.w3schools.com/ 
 **=>** **on click of logo2** it should point to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
**=>** **on click of logo3** 
it should point to https://github.com/
**=>** **on click of logo4** it should point to https://www.espncricinfo.com/

Comment: All your anchors are stacked together positioned absolutely, since there is no z-index change when you fade, the last one will always be on top of the others. When something has opacity of 0, it is only hidden visually, the item is still there

Comment: @Huangism Is there any way, we can fixed that ?

Comment: You can animate with key frames and change the z-index of each item accordingly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278524/infinite-animation-keyframes-z-index-issue-at-the-end-of-the-cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's figure out what's happening :

- all the `a` elements that form the cross-fade gallery are stacked on top of each other due to `position:absolute !important` rule.
- the last `a` element (`logo4`) is the last `a` in the markup so it will be the top one in the appearance.
- the `opacity` just fades the element and it doesn't move it nor *remove* it temporarily thus the last `a` tag still on the top even if it doesn't appear while cross-fading.

So how to fix that, simply modify the `keyframe` and add a high, `999` for example (higher than `1`), `z-index` rule when the `opacity` is set to `1` (the element is visible) and revert it to `1` when the `opacity` is `0` (the element is *hidden*).

Here's a demo :

```css
.featured-block__item {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 2rem);
  width: calc(25% - 2rem);
}

.featured-block__image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.featured-block a {
  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 16s;
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;z-index: 999;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;z-index: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-block" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
  <!-- For Position one -->
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="http://i.imgur.com/EUqZ1Er.png" data-fallback-img="http://i.imgur.com/EUqZ1Er.png" alt="Outburst">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="http://i.imgur.com/D5yaJeW.png" data-fallback-img="http://i.imgur.com/D5yaJeW.png" alt="L'Essentiel with Esther Bégin">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="http://i.imgur.com/R7A9JXc.png" data-fallback-img="http://i.imgur.com/R7A9JXc.png" alt="PrimeTime Politics">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://i.imgur.com/YhaIsPB.png" data-fallback-img="https://i.imgur.com/YhaIsPB.png" alt="PrimeTime Politics">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- For Position one -->
</div>
```

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks for the help. I have one more minor change. I am wondering what changes I should make in the code so that animation starts from logo1 and then logo2 and then logo3 and logo4.

Comment: At this moment, animation happens from log4 => logo3 => logo2 => logo1

Comment: I am thinking, if we can do like this logo1 => logo2 => logo3 => logo4

Comment: When it moves from `logo1 -> logo2 -> logo3 -> logo4` initially, I can see **no tiles for a fraction of seconds**.  In short when it switch from `logo1 -> logo2, logo2 -> logo3, logo3 -> logo4, logo4 -> logo1` I see nothing for a small amount of time.

Comment: I think, the previous style was much better. I am wondering what changes I need to make so that it come back to the previous animation style but from `top to bottom (logo1 -> logo2 -> logo3 -> logo4)` which is right now.